# xna model scaling - model is bigger than world

Tags: xna, c#, models, scale

I'm having trouble scaling my model in XNA with C#. The model is bigger than the world itself and I can't seem to scale it down. Below is the code I'm using and an attached screenshot. How can I scale my model down?

```
       private void DrawModel(Matrix currentViewMatrix)
    {

        Matrix[] bones = animationPlayer.GetSkinTransforms();

        // Compute camera matrices.
        Matrix view = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, -40, 0) *
                      Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(cameraRotation_model)) *
                      Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(cameraArc)) *
                      Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, -cameraDistance),
                                          new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.Up);

        float fieldOfView = MathHelper.ToRadians(4);

        Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(fieldOfView, device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1, 100000);

        // Render the skinned mesh.
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in currentModel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (SkinnedEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.SetBoneTransforms(bones);

                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;

                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();

                effect.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0.25f);
                effect.SpecularPower = 16;
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

**edit**: when I change the following lines, I'm able to scale the model, however when I turn my model, it rotates in a circle; the model isn't properly scaled. If I do not scale the model, it turns properly around itself.

How can I fix this?

```
Matrix view = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, -50, 0) *
                      Matrix.CreateScale(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f) *
                      Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(cameraRotation_model)) *
                      Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(cameraArc)) *
                      Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, -cameraDistance),
                                          new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.Up);
```

[image: Model out of proportions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first scale and rotate, and then translate:

```
        Vector3 objPos = new Vector3(0, -50, 0);
        Vector3 camPos = objPos - Vector3.One * cameraDistance;
        Matrix view = 
                  Matrix.CreateScale(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f) *
                  Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(cameraRotation_model)) *
                  Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(cameraArc)) *
                  Matrix.CreateTranslation(objPos) *
                  Matrix.CreateLookAt(camPos, obsPos, Vector3.Up);
```

EDITED: Because camera was placed where object was not.

Comment: thanks for your help. I did try that before you posted, if I use 0.01f as scale, the model 'doesn't show up (it probably does but not visible)'. I can only get the model to show again if I use a scale above 1f. Am I missing something essential?

Comment: It's due to the camera position, the lookat args have to be changed

Comment: thanks, I get "No overload for method 'CreateTranslation' takes 0 arguments" - I've tried to add '0, -10, 0' as value but then the model isn't visible

Comment: btw: is it possible (or even an decent idea) to scale the world instead of the model ?

Comment: The best would be separate model trasforms from camera transforms, so you can scale, translate and rotate the models, and only calculate camera transform once time.